# How sys_sigreturn get parameter in Linux 2.4.0?

Tags: c, kernel

Recently, I am studying the signal handle operation in 2.4.0 of Linux. Here is the question

```
asmlinkage int sys_sigreturn(unsigned long __unused)
{
    struct pt_regs *regs = (struct pt_regs *) &__unused;
    struct sigframe *frame = (struct sigframe *)(regs->esp - 8);
    sigset_t set;
    int eax;

    if (verify_area(VERIFY_READ, frame, sizeof(*frame)))
        goto badframe;
    if (__get_user(set.sig[0], &frame->sc.oldmask)
        || (_NSIG_WORDS > 1
        && __copy_from_user(&set.sig[1], &frame->extramask,
                    sizeof(frame->extramask))))
        goto badframe;

    sigdelsetmask(&set, ~_BLOCKABLE);
    spin_lock_irq(&current->sigmask_lock);
    current->blocked = set;
    recalc_sigpending(current);
    spin_unlock_irq(&current->sigmask_lock);

    if (restore_sigcontext(regs, &frame->sc, &eax))
        goto badframe;
    return eax;
```

I didn't see code set the %ebx, how did sys_sigreturn get the parameter? Why this parameter is the same address as something in the process user mode stack. The parameter should in registers!Thank you very much!